# How do you set a value to a pointer containing nil using reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I'm trying to set a value to a nil pointer in a struct like so.

```
// https://play.golang.org/p/jPTMNC_ZQ9
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type T struct {
    A *int
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    t := &T{}

    v := 1
    vptr := &v

    CopyValue(vptr, t.A) // I want to set t.A to contain 1
}

func CopyValue(src interface{}, dest interface{}) {
    srcRef := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    if srcRef.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        srcRef = srcRef.Elem()
    }

    destRef := reflect.New(srcRef.Type()).Elem()
    destRef.Set(srcRef)
    reflect.ValueOf(dest).Elem().Set(destRef)
}
```

However, I encounter the following error:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Set on zero Value

goroutine 1 [running]:
reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable(0x0, 0x1040a128)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:221 +0x260
reflect.Value.Set(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xdefc0, 0x1040a128, 0x182)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1339 +0x40
main.CopyValue(0xd7860, 0x1040a124, 0xd7860, 0x0)
    /tmp/sandbox487854080/main.go:30 +0x1a0
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox487854080/main.go:19 +0x100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aside: it's perhaps more intuitive to pass and copy `v` rather than passing `vptr` and copying `*vptr`; if you want to copy `*vptr`, then pass `*vptr` instead of `vptr`. See https://play.golang.org/p/daDVbMp3em for an example that will avoid runtime panics.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune what a GREAT example! I thought I was setting the value T.A was pointing to, when I should be setting the address &T.A was pointing to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be able to modify what `t.A` points to, you need to send a reference to it to your `CopyValue` function.

```
CopyValue(vptr, &t.A) // (note the &)
```

You can then assign the pointer to the new address:

```
func CopyValue(src interface{}, dest interface{}) {
    srcRef := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    vp := reflect.ValueOf(dest)
    vp.Elem().Set(srcRef)
}
```

See the 3rd "law of reflection" here: https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

Full working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type T struct {
    A *int
}

func main() {
    t := &T{}
    v := 1
    vptr := &v
    CopyValue(vptr, &t.A) // we pass a reference to t.A since we want to modify it
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", *t.A)
}

func CopyValue(src interface{}, dest interface{}) {
    srcRef := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    vp := reflect.ValueOf(dest)
    vp.Elem().Set(srcRef)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`reflect.ValueOf(dest).Elem().Set(destRef)`

If you look into this line, `reflect.ValueOf(dest)` will give you nil, since you passed in a nil pointer. Calling `.Elem()` on this is invalid, since there is no element to the nil pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`t.A` is a nil pointer when you pass it in, so `CopyValue` is being asked to copy a value into an invalid (nil) location.  You need to allocate space for an int for it to point to, and then `CopyValue` will be able to do the copy into the location pointed at.

This resolves the error and allows the value to be copied:

```
t := &T{}
t.A = new(int) // Add this line
```

Comment: Alternatively, `&t.A` could be passed, and `reflect.New` could be used. https://play.golang.org/p/daDVbMp3em (I didn't use `srcRef.Elem()` or `vptr` because it's more intuitive to me to copy `v` rather than `*vptr`)